# Can an in memory object take associations in Rails? Non-traditional form view

Tags: forms, memory, ruby-on-rails-4, associations

I am having a structural problem with submitting and displaying data in a rails view. For my project creation view, a user can add skill requirements to the project. However, the project only exists in memory so when I go to assign skills to it in the create action of the skill controller, I run into an error. Moreover, when the create action redirects one to the project new form, the memory is lost. Therefore, I am not too sure if being able to associate an in memory project object with skill objects is even helpful.

Can someone show me how I can assign skills to a project which only exits in memory? Or create a collection of skills, display that collection as the user clicks add skill, and then assign these collection of skills to the project in the project create action when the user clicks, "Create", for creating a project?

**Models:**

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :requirements
  has_many :skills, through: :requirements
end

class Skill < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :requirements
  has_many :projects, through: :requirements
end

class Requirement < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  belongs_to :skill
end
```

**Controllers:**

```
class SkillsController < ApplicationController
  def create

    if params[:project] && Skill.where(name: params[:skill][:name]) != []
      skill = Skill.where(name: params[:skill][:name]).first
      @project_skills = []
      @project_skills << skill
    else
      skill = Skill.create(name: params[:skill][:name]) if params[:skill][:name]
      @project_skills = []
      @project_skills << skill
    end
end

class OrganizationAdmin::ProjectsController < OrganizationAdminController
  before_action :find_organization, only: [:create]

  def new
    @project = Project.new(organization_id: params[:organization_id])
    @skill = Skill.new
    @all_skills = Skill.all
    @project_skills
  end

  def create
    @project = Project.new(project_params)
    if @project.save
      @project.update_columns(state: "open", causes: @organization.cause)
      creates_a_newsfeed_item_for_the_project(@project)
      flash[:notice] = "You successfully created a project"
      redirect_to project_path(@project.id)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
```

**Views**

```
%section#form.register
  .row.row-custom
    .col-lg-10.col-project-form
      = form_for [:organization_admin, @project], html: {class: 'form-horizontal'} do |f|
        %h1 Create a Project
        %fieldset
          .row
            .col-lg-5
              .form-group#deadline
                %label.control-label.col-lg-3 Deadline
                .col-lg-9.project-gen-input-fix
                  = f.date_select(:deadline, :order => [:month, :day, :year])
            .col-lg-3
              .form-group#hours
                %label.control-label.col-lg-8{:for => "estimated-hours"} Estimated Hours
                .col-lg-4
                  = f.text_field :estimated_hours, class: "form-control input-sm"
          .form-group
            %label.control-label.col-lg-2 Project Title
            .col-lg-10
              = f.text_field :title, class: "form-control"
              = hidden_field_tag :skills, @project_skills
          .form-group
            %label.control-label.col-lg-2 Description
            .col-lg-10
              = f.text_area :description, cols: 6, rows: 6, class: "form-control"
            = f.hidden_field :organization_id
          .form-group
            = f.submit "Create", class: "btn btn-lg btn-primary pull-right"
      = form_for @skill, url: skills_path do |f|
        %div.edit-input-wrapper
          = f.label :skill_requirements
          = f.text_field :name, data: {autocomplete_source: skill_set(@all_skills)}
          = hidden_field_tag :project, @project
        = f.submit "Add Skill", class: "btn btn-success", id: "edit-submit"
      %ul
        - @project_skills.each do |type|
          %li= type.name
    .col-lg-2
      %p#form-tip <strong>Tip</strong>: The dreams of yesterday are the hopes of today and <a href="#">the reality of tomorrow</a>.
```

Comment: Just save your `@project` before attempting to assign skills to it.

Comment: That's a very nice idea. However, I think I'm going to have to create a new object called, Draft. In order to be RESTful, a project can only be created when it hits the create action in the projects controller

Answer (score 0):

To follow up on this question, I created two buttons on my project form: one for saving a draft and the other for publishing a project. In the create project action, I detect which button is being clicked by the commit params. However, for adding skills to a project or to a draft I had to create another form on the page. However, this adding skills form still goes to the same project action.

When a draft is saved, a project is created but not published to the project index. Each time I save the draft I route back to the new action of the project, passing in the appropriate parameters to keep rendering the form with the accurate inputs. The same thing happens for adding a skill.

A new problem has appeared, however. I need to do some major refactor on my projects create action. I created a [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24827732/how-do-i-refactor-this-projects-create-action-in-rails) to see if anyone had suggestions on thinning this action.